# C# Split Date and Time format into Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a CSV with a server log. I need to split the date/time format as attached image into my datatable.

Sample of CSV txt file

> 10.115.10.74 - - [20/Mar/2016:03:38:14 +0800] "GET /portal/images/banners/iot.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 918 "http://www.utem.edu.my/portal/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
>
> 172.16.75.219 - - [20/Mar/2016:03:38:17 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36"

Is there any way I can do to achieve something like this?

[image: expected]

What I have tried so far

```
string[] raw_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\log4.csv");

string[] data_col = null;

int x = 0;
foreach (string text_line in raw_text)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(text_line);
    data_col = text_line.Split(' ', '<', '>', '[', ']', '-', '"', ';', '(', ')', '+', ':');


    if (x == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            my_datatable.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
        }

        x++;
    }
    else
    {

        my_datatable.Rows.Add(data_col);
    }
```

Comment: Post a text version of the csv so we can test things easier.

Comment: updated, sorry for any inconvenience..

Comment: How are you displaying this data? If it's some form of grid control, is it possible it offers the ability to bind multiple columns in the grid to a single column of data, and then to format those columns independently? Meaning you can keep the *data* intact in the data table and just adjust how it's *displayed*.

Comment: Actually your code suffers split problem in time part due to `:` character used as split character (e.g. `20/Mar/2016, 03, 38, 14, 0800`). I think `DateTime.TryParse` with `dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss` format may handle this issue.

Comment: I suggest you to use an appropriate CSV parser library. This format is enough complex to be handled by home made code like the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based this answer from your existing source code. Adjust it to your needs.

From the sample log file:

```
10.115.10.74 - - [20/Mar/2016:03:38:14 +0800] "GET /portal/images/banners/iot.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 918 "http://www.utem.edu.my/portal/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
172.16.75.219 - - [20/Mar/2016:03:38:17 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36"
```

Console application:

```
class Foo
{
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Request { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Log.txt");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("IP Address");
        dt.Columns.Add("Date");
        dt.Columns.Add("Time");
        dt.Columns.Add("GMT");
        dt.Columns.Add("Method");

        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            string[] split = line.Split(' ', '<', '>', '[', ']', '-', '"', ';', '(', ')', '+', ':');

            split = split.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r)).ToArray();

            Foo foo = new Foo();

            foo.IPAddress = split[0];
            foo.Date = split[1];
            foo.Time = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", split[2], split[3], split[4]);
            foo.TimeZone = split[5];
            foo.Request = split[6];

            dt.Rows.Add(foo.IPAddress, foo.Date, foo.Time, foo.TimeZone, foo.Request);
        }

        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4]));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: I tried this method, but i load using  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\log4.csv"); but it appear blank window output. any idea?

Comment: updated - it loads, but i dont know why it didnt seperate the date/time part into different column. i tried exactly what you did.. i dont know what could be possibly wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code. I hope it helps

```
        string[] raw_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\log4.csv");
        string[] data_col = null;

        int x = 0;

        foreach (string text_line in raw_text)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(text_line);
            data_col = text_line.Split(' ', '<', '>', '[', ']', '-', '"', ';', '(', ')', '+', ':');


            if (x == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                        my_datatable.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                        my_datatable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(data_col[i]).ToString("ddMMMyyyy"));

                        my_datatable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(data_col[i]).ToString("HH:mm tt"));

                         my_datatable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(data_col[i]).ToString("zzz"));

                        my_datatable.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                }

                x++;
            }
            else
            {

                my_datatable.Rows.Add(data_col);
            }
```

Comment: Tried, it wont do. Thank you for your reply sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way; This is a skeleton. You will need to loop through, (or use linq) to convert dates. Make below code a function and pass the date as a parameter.

```
    var parts = ("20/Mar/2016:03:38:17 +800").Split(':').ToList();
    var datePart = parts[0];
    var timePart = parts.Except(new[]{datePart});   
    var timeString = string.Join(":", timePart);
    var time = timeString.Split('+')[0];
    var gmt = "+" + timeString.Split('+')[1];
    Console.WriteLine(datePart);
    Console.WriteLine(time);
    Console.WriteLine(gmt);
```